# Warum schreibt man nicht »Sand strahlen«?

Tags: verb, compound

Laut [Rechtschreibregel 54](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#K54) wird bei »nicht verblassten« Substantiven »in den meisten Fällen« getrennt geschrieben.

Demnach würde ich »Sand strahlen« schreiben, aber ich finde überall nur die Form »sandstrahlen«.
Gibt es da eine Begründung?

Und was ist mit anderen »Strahlmitteln« statt Sand. Schreibt man (als Verb) z.B. »ich habe [trockeneisgestrahlt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trockeneisstrahlen)«, »ich habe [gekugelstrahlt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelstrahlen)« oder doch »ich habe [Soda gestrahlt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodastrahlen)«?

Comment: Ich würde "kugelgestrahlt" verwenden.

Comment: Weil es Strahlen mit und nicht von Sand ist, aber ich habe keine Regel dazu.

Answer (score 9):

Bei *sandstrahlen* handelt es sich um eine Zusammensetzung und nicht um eine lose Gruppe von Wörtern. Es wäre sonst sehr schwierig, in einem Satz wie *Wir müssen das Teil noch Sand strahlen* die Anwesenheit von zwei Objekten zu erklären (*das Teil den Sand strahlen*, Akkusativ? *das Teil dem Sand strahlen*, Dativ?); ein weiteres Indiz ist die alleinige Betonung auf der ersten Silbe.

Die möglichen Schreibweisen hängen davon ab, ob der Schreiber das Verb als trennbare (*ich habe sandgestrahlt*) oder untrennbare (*ich habe gesandstrahlt*) Zusammensetzung auffassen will; der Gebrauch schwankt. Für nicht trennbare Zusammensetzungen von Substantiv und Verb (Beispiel *handhaben*) gilt nach § 33 der [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) Zusammenschreibung; für trennbare Zusammensetzungen (Beispiel *stattfinden*) gilt dagegen nach § 34 (3) im Prinzip Getrenntschreibung, allerdings werden die Teile doch verbunden, wenn sie in Infinitiven, Partizipien oder am Ende eines Nebensatzes zusammentreffen: *es findet statt*, aber *es hat stattgefunden*.

Im Ergebnis heißt es also nach Wahl des Schreibers entweder *er sandstrahlt das Teil* oder *er strahlt das Teil sand*. Zumindest nach Ansicht des Dudens wird *sandstrahlen* aber „gewöhnlich nur im Infinitiv und 2. Partizip“ gebraucht, wo es in jedem Fall in einem Wort geschrieben wird.

Die Duden-Rechtschreibregeln sind ein Versuch, die amtliche Regelung mit ihren vielen Sonderfällen verständlicher zusammenzufassen. Sie sind nicht vollständig und nicht verbindlich.

Comment: Ich habe keine Probleme mit »Wir müssen das Teil noch Sand strahlen.«. Statt »den Sand« oder »dem Sand« ginge »mit Sand«. Ansonsten nimmt man die Erklärung, die das »Auto« in »Wir müssen gleich noch Auto fahren.« beschreibt. (Ich bin nur selber nicht so gut in formaler Grammatik und weiß nicht wie das grammatikalisch richtig heißt.)

Comment: @ospalh: Das _mit_ ist aber nicht da. Ebenso ist der Auto-Fall nicht vergleichbar, weil eben kein weiteres Objekt auftaucht; man kann nicht etwas sagen wie _Wir müssen gleich noch das Kind Auto fahren_.

Comment: Und wenn wir statt eines Autos eine Probe fahren? Da gibt es ein weiteres Objekt. »Wir müssen auch noch den Benz Probe fahren.« Ich zumindest finde »Wir müssen auch noch mit dem Benz eine Probefahrt machen« viel zu umständlich. Und ich sage auch nicht »Wir müssen auch noch den Benz {zur|auf|die} Probe fahren.«.

Comment: Ich stimme voll zu. Die Frage ist, ob es "wir sandstrahlen das Teil" oder "wir strahlen das Teil Sand" heißt :)

Comment: @ospalh: Ich bin mir weiterhin nicht sicher, ob wir nicht aneinander vorbeireden. Aber _Probe fahren_ ist jedenfalls tatsächlich eine Entsprechung zu (der trennbaren Version von) _sandstrahlen_. Wer _sandgestrahlt_ schreibt, müßte auch _probegefahren_ schreiben, und umgekehrt gehörte _Sand gestrahlt_ zu _Probe gefahren_; warum der Duden beides unterschiedlich behandeln will, ist in der Tat rätselhaft. Die Schreibung „Probe fahren“ ist im Wörterverzeichnis zur amtlichen Regelung 2006 so vorgesehen (ohne Begründung), halte ich aber für falsch; möglicherweise ein Relikt von 1996?

Answer (score 2):

Regel 54 ist grenzwertig in diesem Fall.  Man könnte argumentieren, dass der Sand in sandstrahlen seine Eigenständigkeit verloren hat, denn jetzt ist es ein Strahl und eben nicht mehr nur Sand.  Außerdem gibt es keine wirkliche transitive Form von "strahlen".  "Etwas strahlen" ist seltsam, daher wirkt "Sand strahlen" für mich falsch. Das gleiche Argument trifft auch auf andere Strahlmaterialen zu.

Bemerkung: "sodastrahlen/Soda strahlen" gibt es meiner Meinung nach nicht. Was soll es bedeuten?

Im Zweifelsfall gibt es auch noch [Verblisten die die zusammengesetzten Verben einfach auflisten](http://verblisten.de/listen/verben/anfangsbuchstabe/zusammengesetzt/vollstaendig-3.html): sandstrahlen taucht auf, kugelstrahlen aber nicht.

Comment: Sodastrahlen (Hauptwort, klar ein Wort) hatte ich im OP verlinkt. Man benutzt im Wesentlichen Backpulver statt Sand, Trockeneis, Kugeln, ….

Comment: (Womitauchimmer-)strahlen ist doch ein Bearbeitungsvorgang. »Die verrostete Felge wurde sandgestrahlt« (oder eben (nicht) »Die verrostete Felge wurde Sand gestrahlt«) ist doch schönstes passiv. Für mich unterscheidet sich dies transitive »etwas strahlen« = »etwas mit einem Strahl bearbeiten« klar von dem nicht-transitiven »strahlen« (wie die Sonne, Plutonium usw.).

Comment: @ospalh Ach ja, den Link zu Sodastrahlen hatte ich nicht beachtet. "etwas strahlen" ist für mich immer noch sehr umgangssprachlich (Handwerkersprache?)

Answer (score 0):

Es werden für die diversen Strahltechniken wohl nur die Hauptwörter verwendet: Druckluftstrahlen (als Oberbegriff), Trockeneisstrahlen usw. Nur sandstrahlen scheint als Verb üblich zu sein und taucht so im Duden auf.

Anders als z. B. bei »(Auto, Rad, so ziemlich alles was Räder hat) fahren« gibt es das transitive Verb »etwas strahlen« eigentlich nicht. Folglich auch nicht die Zusammensetzung »etwas (Druckluft, Trockeneis usw.) + strahlen«.

Ich finde transitiv »strahlen« nur praktischer als »durch Strahlen bearbeiten«.
»Strahl das mal Trockeneis.« ist kürzer als »Reinige das durch Trockeneisstrahlen.« (Und man würde eher nicht 
Und da es eben diverse Strahlmittel gibt sind die Hauptwörter mit denen man dieses neue Verb gebrauchen könnte nicht »verblasst« (Duden) oder haben »die Eigenschaften selbständiger Substantive« (Rechtschreibrat) nicht verloren.
Wenn man doch dieser Meinung wäre, könnte man eine Reihe von Zusammensetzungen bilden, die Verben »druckluftstrahlen«, »kugelstrahlen« usw. Das geht aber nicht mehr wenn man z. B. Strahlmittel mischt. [Anscheinend](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trockeneisstrahlen#Abrasives_Trockeneisstrahlen) setzt man manchmal zu Trockeneis andere Stoffe zu, und man müsste so etwas wie »trockeneisundnussschalenstrahlen« bilden. Oder man sagt »mit Trockeneis und Nussschalen strahlen«. Derzeitiger Standard scheint hier aber zu sein, das ganze zu umschiffen: »durch Strahlen mit Trockeneis und Nussschalen reinigen«.

Nur wenn man »strahlen« als ein neues, eigenständiges, transitives Verb benutzt kann man auch »Sand strahlen« statt »sandtrahlen« schreiben.

Edit: Stimmt. Das »Trockeneis strahl das mal.«, das ich zuerst geschrieben habe, wäre falsch herum.

Comment: Funktioniert immer noch nicht, sobald „Sand strahlen“ selbst ein Objekt bekommt. Außerdem ist für die Zusammenschreibung von nicht trennbaren Zusammensetzungen Verblassen keine Voraussetzung; und wenn du sagst „Trockeneisstrahl das mal“, benutzt du es als nicht trennbares Verb, sonst müßte es nämlich „Strahl das mal trockeneis“ heißen.